# match function in javascript getting error when comparing with number in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, match

This is an array in angular 2

```js
export const COMPANIES: any = [
  { 'comp_id': 353, 'name': 'oakridge It Solns', 'location': 'USA' },
  { 'comp_id': 354, 'name': 'VPDCS', 'location': 'Russia' },
  { 'comp_id': 355, 'name': 'Microsoft', 'location': 'USA' },
  { 'comp_id': 356, 'name': 'Google', 'location': 'Germany' },
  { 'comp_id': 357, 'name': 'Amazon', 'location': 'France' },
  { 'comp_id': 358, 'name': 'Facebook', 'location': 'France' },
];
```

Onsubmit event from html click event the  below function executes.
It is working fine for strings, but getting error when I supply any
 number in search value

```js
onSubmit(mySearch) {    
  if (mySearch.table_Value === 'Select Table' && mySearch.text_value === '') {
    this.errorMsg = "Please provide field and serch text";
  } else {
    let filArray = [];
    for (let data of this.dataArray) {
      var re = new RegExp(mySearch.text_value, 'gi');
      //not working for numbers...
      //if (data[mySearch.field_Value].match(re)) {
      if(data[mySearch.field_Value].match('^.*'+mySearch.text_value+'.*$')){
        filArray.push(data);
      }
    }
    this.dataArray = filArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the error

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the number may have to be casted into a string so it can be properly used within the regex:

```
      var re = new RegExp(""+mySearch.text_value, 'gi');
```

or

```
      var re = new RegExp(String(mySearch.text_value), 'gi');
```